# How to optimize COUNT query on GIN and B-Tree indexed table in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, count

I have a Postgres 12 table `foo` that looks like this:

| Column | Type | Index Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| createdAt | timestamp without time zone | btree |
| email | text | gin (email gin_trgm_ops) |
| message | text | gin (message gin_trgm_ops) |

I don't have any other indices created on this table. The actual table has more than 10 million rows

My query is dynamically generated, the main query is

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo
```

The conditions may vary. Sometimes it does not have any conditions, but sometimes it can contain conditions like this:

```sql
WHERE 
LOWER(email) LIKE LOWER('%<parameter here>%') 
AND LOWER(message) LIKE LOWER('%<parameter here>%') 
AND createdAt > '<timestamp here>' 
AND created < '<timestamp here>'
```

These four conditions is the most complex case. Most cases only `email` and `message` are compared.

I noticed that a conditioned query is always way slower than an unconditioned one. How can I improve the performance, especially given that `email` and `message` are queried together very often? Is a multi-column index with GIN a viable solution? How much improvement would it give?

**[EDIT]**
Here is the output of `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` from a smaller instance.

```
explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) select count(*) from public."foo" where lower(message) like lower('%acme.com%') and lower(email) like lower('%acme.com%');
                                                             QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=33139.84..33139.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=183.940..185.917 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   Buffers: shared hit=29989
   ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..33139.83 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=183.935..185.912 rows=0 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=29989
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on public."foo"  (cost=0.00..32139.73 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=179.472..179.473 rows=0 loops=3)
               Filter: ((lower("foo".message) ~~ '%acme.com%'::text) AND (lower("foo".email) ~~ '%acme.com%'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 86166
               Buffers: shared hit=29989
               Worker 0: actual time=177.051..177.051 rows=0 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=10517
               Worker 1: actual time=180.233..180.233 rows=0 loops=1
                 Buffers: shared hit=9736
 Planning Time: 0.090 ms
 Execution Time: 185.950 ms
(17 rows)
```

**[Edit] 2** Partial output from `\d+ public."foo"`

```
%%%%=> \d+ public."foo";
                                                       Table "public.foo"
    Column     |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |      Default      | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id            | text                           |           | not null |                   | extended |              |
 createdAt     | timestamp(3) without time zone |           | not null | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | plain    |              |
 email         | text                           |           | not null |                   | extended |              |
 message       | text                           |           | not null |                   | extended |              |

Indexes:
    "foo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "foo_createdAt_idx" btree ("createdAt")
    "foo_email_idx" gin (email gin_trgm_ops)
    "foo_message_idx" gin (message gin_trgm_ops)
Access method: heap
```

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for your SQL statements? And the DDL for the table and its indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update to your original question. And did you install the pg_trgm module? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.44.8

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thank you, I have added it. Also, what is DDL? Yes, I have pg_trgm module installed.

Comment: DDL is the Data Definition Language, the SQL used to create your tables, indexes and other database objects.

Comment: As you can see, none of your indexes is used. Give it a try with pg_trgm, create a new index (see the manual) and try again.

Comment: I am using `pg_trgm` module to create the index using the GIN function. So, I am not sure if that would make a difference. If you believe GIST would be better, could you please explain why? Also, "see the manual" is quite vague.

Comment: You created an index on "email", not on "LOWER(email)". Because of that, the index will not be used. Are you sure about the case sensitivity anyway? If not, don't use LOWER() and instead of LIKE use ILIKE

Comment: @nbk That is what pg_trgm can solve for you

Comment: If `count()` queries are really your most problematic queries, you are doing something wrong. I bet it is the old mistake of displaying [total result set counts](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/#total-count). The correct solution is simple: don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL has the ILIKE operator which is case insensitive, and trigram indexes inherently support it.  `LOWER(.) LIKE LOWER LOWER (.)` on the other is not inherently supported.  You could build an expression index to support it, but there is little point since ILIKE is shorter, faster, and (in my opinion) easier to understand.